# XAMPP relative urls not working correctly

Tags: php, xampp, relative-path

on http://www.exampleSite.com/aPage.php, the following image loads correctly

```
<img src="/images/sidenav/analysis-2.gif" />
```

but at http://localhost/exampleSite/aPage.php, it tries to get localhost/images/... instead of localhost/exampleSite/images/...

My file structure is:

C:\xampp\htdocs\exampleSite\

I have had this problem across multiple projects, and have previously resorted to absolute URLs, but now I am just trying to make some quick updates on a page, and I cannot view it correctly on my localhost.

Comment: Do you have any active mod_rewrite rules?

Comment: I have no .htaccess files in play, should I did deeper?

Comment: In my situation, the reverse is the case, i.e.  at http://localhost/exampleSite/aPage.php, it tries to get localhost/exampleSite/images/..., BUT I need to get localhost/images/... Any idea how this can be done?

Comment: @HammanSamuel not really the best venue to ask that (better for a new question) but if your link starts with `/images` it *should* go to `localhost/images`. You can also experiment with `../images/path/to/file.jpg` (the `../` means "up a directory")

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you don't want to mess up with the src attributes throughout your website, you may consider changing configuration directives.

You can relocate it by editing the `DocumentRoot` setting in `C:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf`.

It should be currently set as :

```
C:/xampp/htdocs
```

Change it to:

```
C:/xampp/htdocs/exampleSite
```

and your relative link as `<img src="/images/sidenav/analysis-2.gif" />` should be working fine.

**NOTE:**

- Don't forget to restart your XAMPP Server after making changes.
- After these changes, your leading `/` will always direct to the `exampleSite` folder. Should you decide to change the root later, repeat the process for the root folder of your choice.

Comment: So this will work as a temporary fix?  Sounds like the best option so far.  This means however that I cannot work on exampleSite, and exampleSite2 at the same time without changing the DocumentRoot back and forth

Comment: TRUE. Changing your DocumentRoot is easier than src attributes throughout your website, i believe :)

Answer (score 5):

Remove the first `/` so that it becomes

`<img src="images/sidenav/analysis-2.gif" />`

Comment: You could also use `<img src="../images/sidenav/analysis-2.gif" />` or `<img src="../../images/sidenav/analysis-2.gif" />` depending on how many directories you need to go up.

Comment: This isn't the reliable answer. OP wouldn't like to change the src between remote and local server while downloading/uploading.

Comment: @GhazanfarMir His problem comes from the leading `/` since he doesn't seem to have the same directory structure between the local server and the remote one.

Comment: Hmmm, I realize I misspoke before, and said quick updates on a 'page' when I should have done 'site'.  There are multiple files invloved.  I guesse I can do a bulk find-replace for '"/images'.  Is there any other way you can think of to approach this?

Comment: Depending on the structure of your website and the location of the html/php file you may be able to do a find/replace on all the files. You should take into consideration @DanLehmann's comment.

Comment: I still don't understand why this discrepancy exists however.  What is it precisely that the leading slash is doing?  On my localhost it acts like ../ and on the webhost it is ignored?

Comment: I think I answered my own question (sort of).  The leading / apparently points to the document root (localhost/ or www.example.com/) rather than the current folder.